# AWS Elastic Cache Redis java Spring redisson ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, spring, redis, amazon-elasticache, redisson

I have an AWS **Redis** cluster with **Cluster mode Enabled** and **Encryption at rest/transit Enabled** with **Transit encryption mode Preferred**.

I'm using Java spring with `redisson` version 3.12.0 .

Below is my connection using `redisson`:

```
redissonConfig.useClusterServers()
.setKeepAlive(true)
.setConnectTimeout(10000)
.setRetryAttempts(2)
.setDnsMonitoringInterval(10000)
.addNodeAddress("Redis configuration endpoint");
client = Redisson.create(redissonConfig);
```

I using this redis end point : `rediss://ConfigurationEndpoint`

When try to connect to cluster from application using AWS **EC2** and **Jposs** I'm getting this Exception `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException` , also I see below exception

```
[2023-04-15 14:46:22,296] [redisson-netty-2-3] [WARN] ChannelInitializer- Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x77267167]
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:624) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:223) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:381) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:370) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_362]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handlerAdded(SslHandler.java:1979) ~[netty-handler-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72  


[redisson-netty-2-3] [WARN] ChannelInitializer- Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0xe1c3fece]
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
```

I spent more that 15 hours trying to resolve the issue with no luck, also I searched over the internet for such error with no result , appreciate your support incase you have any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT

It tells that you might have different netty versions in classpath

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question, I was able to solve this issue by upgrading the **io.netty**. version to **4.1.72.Final** , as below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.72.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The main issue was with **io.netty** version conflict that I have within my application where multiple versions were used.